# Android: ListView, at the same time remembering and forgetting its getCheckedItemPosition after rotation/configuration change

Tags: android, android-listview, android-configchanges

I really can't make this up so I'd be thankful for any hint. I must make some mistake here (4.1.2).

I have an `Activity` which, in `onCreate()`, sets up a subclassed `ArrayAdapter` for `ListView` items which render as a `Checkable` `ViewGroup`.

The `Activity` already utilizes a `NonConfiguration` mechanism to re-build the Adapter upon orientation change. However, it's currently not storing the `ListView`'s `getCheckedItemPosition()` because I feel it shouldn't be necessary (details below).

Interestingly, what I'm observing is the following.

- The Activity is rendered.
- The user checks a ListView item.
- The ListView item is displayed in a checked state.
- The `onItemClickListener` calls `getCheckedItemPosition()` for the `ListView` and gets a correct result.
- The user changes the screen orientation.
- `onCreate()` re-builds the 'ListView' and it displays just like before (after `onCreate()`; see below).
- `onCreate()` calls `getCheckedItemPosition()` and gets `-1` despite the `ListView` showing the correcly checked item

Upon further examination, the following details emerge.

- `onCreate()`:

  - get `ListView` resource
  - build `MyAdapter`
  - set `MyAdapter` as adapter for `ListView`
  - `getCheckedItemPosition()` returns `-1`
- after `onCreate()`:

  - `MyAdapter.getView()` is being called
  - `CheckableViewGroup.setChecked()` is called with the correct `checked` value
  - the last two steps will be repeated for all items

As said before, I'm relying on the Android feature that `View` objects save their state if they have an ID assigned. I'd say this is the case since there must be some object out there which sets the correct `checked` status for all the list entries. (By the way, `CheckableViewGroup` also overrides `on{Save,Restore}InstanceState()` but that won't be called regardless whether or not it has an ID assigned (presumably because it never gets attached to the layout root?).

So it **looks as if the `ListView` at the same time knows and does not know its `getCheckedItemPosition()`**? Or am I on the wrong track?

```
public final class MyActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.my_activity);
        itemList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.ma_list);
        listAdapter = new MyAdapter();
        itemList.setAdapter(listAdapter);
        itemList.setOnItemClickListener(
            new OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> av, View v, int pos, long id) { checkForm(); }
            }
        );
        listAdapterSetup();
        // this is where itemList.getCheckedItemPosition() returns -1
        // when the listView has been re-built from NonConfiguration data:
        checkForm(); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was making another test after I posted my question, because I was getting an idea while describing my observations.

And indeed, my suspicion was confirmed.

**Timing is key** here.

The `ListView` will report the correct `getCheckedItemPosition()` value in `onResume()` (but not before).

So the solution is easy: Perform any evaluation logic in `onResume()`.